# Dashboard contact widgets can't find any results?

Tags: contacts, dashboard

[image]

I have 7000+ contacts synched to my Apple iCloud account. I can see them with the contact app when I search for some of them via spotlight, as shown in the next image:

[image]

But in Dashboard Contact widget, it cannot find any matches with my name or number that I searched for.

What could be the reason the problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Before doing this save your current work.**

Open `System Preferences`, then go to `Security & Privacy` section. In `Privacy` tab select `Contacts` from the list left side. In the right panel check `Dashboard` in the list. By selecting the `Quit Now` button your Dashboard will quit and it might cause logging out and closing your applications. Login again and in Dashboard remove and add the Contact widget again.

Comment: it doesnt work for me :/

Comment: Are you sure about doing this workflow right? I can reproduce your problem with unchecking Dashboard in Privacy and then fix it with this solution.